# C# search list function

Tags: xml, list, search

I have an XML file containing ingredients and recepies. I now want to create an search function, for instance if the user search for "Lasagna" it will find the recipe for the lasagne and display it. Any ideas on how I can start?

Comment: Can you post sample xml?

Answer (score 1):

The easy way will be to use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308960.aspx).

Comment: can u guide me very quick on how?

Comment: Can you post sample of actual xml, I will post liq query for you